# Find the index of character 'a' in array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h.>


int main()
{
char hurray[] = "Hooray for all of us"; //Character String
char *hurrayptr = hurray;   //Pinter to array hurray
int i = 0; //Used in for loop to display position and character
int d = 0; //Used in printf statement to count the position 
int k;
int count = 0;
int index;
int f = 0;

printf("\tPosition\t Character"); 

while (hurray[i] > 20) { 

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {  

        printf("\n\t hurray[%d]\t\t  %c", d++, *hurrayptr++); 

    }
}

for (k = 0; hurray[k]!= '\0'; k++)      
    if ('a' == hurray[k]) {  //specifies character 'a' is to be counted

        count++;    
    }
        printf("\n'A' occurs %d times in this array\n", count); 

        hurrayptr = strchr(hurray, 'a');
        index = (int)(hurrayptr - hurray);
        f++;

        printf("The letter 'a' was find in hurray[%d]\n", index);

return 0;
}
```

Im trying to make it so it displays the number of elements in the array hurray[] then it finds how many times 'a' occured within the array. Then I need to find what the index of 'a' that was found. I can only get it to find the first 'a' after that it stops. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `while (hurray[i] > 20) {` trying to do?

Comment: It loops the printf statements 20 times to display the characters within the array and their index

Comment: You have syntax errors. Try to edit it into something compilable first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
hurrayptr = strchr(hurray, 'a');
index = (int)(hurrayptr - hurray);
f++;

printf("The letter 'a' was find in hurray[%d]\n", index);
```

Only looks for the first letter.  You need to perform these steps in a loop:

```
hurrayptr = strchr(hurray, 'a');
do {
    index = (int)(hurrayptr - hurray);
    printf("The letter 'a' was find in hurray[%d]\n", index);
    hurrayptr = strchr(hurrayptr+1, 'a');
} while (hurrayptr);
```

The first call to `strchr` starts at the beginning of the string, and the call inside of the loop starts looking after the last instance found.

Also, this is not needed:

```
while (hurray[i] > 20) {
```

You have a `for` loop which already prints all the characters.  The `while` is redundant.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes much more sense, Thanks!!